# Search from a list and remove siblings when search result found

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I am trying to add a search filter so that user can find results from this list of contracts while they are typing. E.g.: if a user types "IP", then the top 4 results should be displayed. Following is the function:

```
$('#doc_search').on('keyup', function(){

    var inputtext = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.subdoclist li a').each(function() {
         if(inputtext ==''){
            $('.subdoclist li').each(function(){
                $(this).addClass('show');
            });
             console.log(inputtext);
         } else if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === inputtext) {

            $('.subdoclist li').removeClass('show');
             $(this).parent().addClass('show');
             console.log(inputtext);
         } 

    });
})
```

- '#doc_search' is the search field on top
- '.subdoclist li' are the list items that contain anchor tags with text

At the moment, I have to type exact text and only then the search works.

Fiddle link: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/9tmg5osg/)

Comment: I switched the logic around a bit here: http://jsfiddle.net/n1wxkhkp/ -- if no input, show all the things, otherwise show each one that contains the string somewhere.

Comment: That worked like a charm, you did all the work lol. I'd buy you a beer if you were my colleague, thanks mate. Post this as an answer and I will check it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is with a couple of things fixed up, first I'm using indexOf > -1 to see if the input string is contained within each potential match, and instead of removing show on all of them per-match I do it before it performs the search.

```
$('#doc_search').on('keyup', function() {
  var inputtext = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (inputtext != '') {
    $('.subdoclist li').removeClass('show');
    $('.subdoclist li a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputtext) > -1) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('show');
     }
        });
   } else {
     $('.subdoclist li').addClass('show');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple search, you can check if the text entered is contained on the string like this:
[How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)

You can check each word entered on the search, splitting the string with space delimiter and using a loop but that will take more effort if there too words or a lot if entries.

Comment: I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tmg5osg/2/

But it seems to be not working as required. It searches only one item.

Comment: See my fiddle, you're removing show from all li's every time you make a match.

Answer (score 1):

Short and case-sensitive variant:

```
$('#doc_search').on('keyup', function() {
  var inputtext = $(this).val();
  if (inputtext !== '') {
      $('.subdoclist li').each(function() {
         $(this).toggle($("a:contains('"+ inputtext +"')",$(this)).length > 0);
      });
   } else {
     $('.subdoclist li').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: I didn't want anything cas-sensitive, I got my answer via Adam, I still appreciate your input.